# MariaDB on Docker Linux have two different version between external/internal IP

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb

1. I ran MariaDB as Docker - expose port 3306 to localhost:3307

[image]

2. Connect Database via localhost:3307

   ```
   $ mysql -u tvgift -P 3307 -h localhost -p
   mysql> show databases;
   +--------------------+
   | Database           |
   +--------------------+
   | information_schema |
   +--------------------+
   1 row in set (0.00 sec)
   ```
3. Connect Database via 172.18.0.2:3306 (IP I got from `$ docker inspect <docker ID>`

   ```
   $ mysql -u tvgift -P 3306 -h 172.18.0.2 -p
   mysql> show databases;
   +--------------------+
   | Database           |
   +--------------------+
   | information_schema |
   | tvgift             |
   +--------------------+
   2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
   ```
4. I tried another client (Using mycli) with both IP, result is same.

   ```
   $ mycli mysql://tvgift:tvgift@localhost:3307/tvgift
   mariadb tvgift@localhost:tvgift> show databases;
   +--------------------+
   | Database           |
   +--------------------+
   | information_schema |
   | tvgift             |
   +--------------------+
   2 rows in set
   Time: 0.013s

   $ mycli mysql://tvgift:tvgift@172.18.0.2:3306/tvgift
   mariadb tvgift@172.18.0.2:tvgift> show databases;
   +--------------------+
   | Database           |
   +--------------------+
   | information_schema |
   | tvgift             |
   +--------------------+
   2 rows in set
   Time: 0.013s
   ```

So, only mysql client have differ between two IP of one container service, can you tell me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`localhost` != any IP address.  That is,

```
GRANT ... TO tvgift@'%' ...
```

does *not* include

```
GRANT ... TO tvgift@'localhost' ...
```

If you want to connect both via `localhost` and via an IP address or hostname, you must provide two `GRANTs` with the same permissions (such as `ON tvgift.*`).